# Scroll doesn't allow floating div to show

Tags: html, css

In LTEAdmin, I want to add a scroll to the left menu (because it is very large).

I added this to the CSS to test:

```
.main-sidebar {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 500px;
    min-height: inherit;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 500px;
}
```

But then the elements are hidden behind the scrollbar.

If I remove the `overflow-y: auto`, the scroll disappears but the menus are shown.

Is this because elements can't overflow a scroll bar?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would really help if you could include the relevant HTML as well, forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JorgeeFG  insert html code.